# visual studio 2012 debug for asp.net not working using IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I can´t run visual studio 2012 debug for asp net using IIS7.

I have already tried the following

**ASP NET Settings in IIS**

.NET Compilation: Changed Default Language to c#

**IIS Settings**

ASP:

- Changed script Language to c# (manually)
- Enable Client-side debugging: true
- Enable Server-side debugging: true

Script
 - Language: c#

Also I am using Asp Net v4.0 app pool

Is there any other settings I can change to try make it work?

**EDIT:**

My user is part of Debbuger Users

The error is the following:

Unable to start debbuging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration erros.

**EDIT 2:**

This is the log

```
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
Version: 1.0
Date: 2012-12-18 11:29:55
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-12-18 11:29:55 ::1 DEBUG /tgpwebged/debugattach.aspx - 443 - ::1 - 403 7 5 43
```

**EDIT 3:**

I have manually configured the compilation element in web.config. This is the actuall config:

```
<compilation batch="true" debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" explicit="false" 
maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="10000" maxBatchSize="10000" 
numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" strict="false" 
tempDirectory="C:\Windows\Temp" urlLinePragmas="false"> </compilation>
```

Also just for test purpose changed the user ASP NET V4 app pool runs under to my account. Not the SYSTEM.. my personal account. No success yet.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution.  Sometimes this happens to me and a rebuild fixes it.

Comment: Are you attaching debugger to the right process?

Comment: @Nexus23 yes. I can Attach with no problems. But cannot start debbugging

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution.

Comment: I have done that several times. I still believe that it is a conf parameter that I am missing. I have followed so many tutorials and there is no difference between my app settings and my iis conf. ;O(

Comment: How is a debugging question off topic?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before (although not with VS2012) and the following things have worked:

- Ensure IIS is configured for Integrated Windows Authentication.
- Make sure HTTP Keep Alives are enabled.
- Make sure `http://localhost` is in your trusted sites in your web browser.

Comment: Its is a https connection. But I ll try those options

Comment: All the step above is the way it should be but still can´t get debbug to work. There is no way in google chrome to adds a truted site. Although a valid client certificate is provided by the client and it is accept by the system running withou debbug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach your debugger to the w3wp process and debug that way ?

Here is an article: [Attatch debugger to an IIS process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx)

Comment: Just add the log. Might help. I ll try that

Comment: I cannot attach. Unable to attach to the process. MSVSMON.EXE failed to start.

Comment: @Jamie Townsend Just managed to attach to IIS Process. But how to perform the execution of the code? It is just attached. The is no option to start the application once vs is attached to the process

Comment: IF your using IIS you are running the application already when your are viewing it in a browser. Attach to the process. If you want to debug a certain part of your code set a break point

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following in the command line:

```
cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: I have performed that operation already. Asp net 4 is already installed

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have to run Visual Studio as a local administrator for debugging to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into something similar on VS2010 with a site hosted on IIS7.5.  I'm trying to hit F5 and get my website to start up an automatically attach a debugger.

I think the key is this line in your log:

```
2012-12-18 11:29:55 ::1 DEBUG /tgpwebged/debugattach.aspx - 443 - ::1 - 403 7 5 43
```

As far as I know, debugattach.aspx is some sort of hook that VS will try to invoke before it can actually start up and run your app.  Details are a bit sketchy on the interwebs about what this thing actually *is*, however it does seem that if you don't get a 200 (success) VS won't be able to automatically attach.  Basically it fails on step 1.  In your log, you have a 403 (authorization error) for this request, I have a 404 (not found) in my log.

In your specific case, you might have something in your IIS config that's blocking the DEBUG verb.  It's a common security practice to block uncommon verbs or anything other than POST and GET.  In my case, it's probably similar - the aspx extension is probably being filtered out.  It could also be the default authentication settings for the app in question.

**Update:** I did solve this on my end, and two separate things were wrong.  First, I was using UrlScan.dll for security and it was blocking the DEBUG verb.  Also, I was using a UrlRewrite rule to go from HTTP to HTTPS and the 302 redirect it generated also blocked this VS request.  I was able to find both issues using the IIS Failed Request Tracing feature.  The logs from that tool give some insight on what various modules and handlers in the pipeline are doing.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same situation. I have solved it and here's how I did it:

- Check if it's the right .NET Framework edition on the IIS.
- Check your application pool's pipeline mode, for some apps - it only allows `Classic mode`.
- Check if there's any other application under the application which you want to debug.

Comment: Using the markup for lists makes the post a little more readable.