# Asp.Net debbuging in vs2012 fails when using https requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I started this question today:

[visual studio 2012 debug for asp.net not working using IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931640/visual-studio-2012-debug-for-asp-net-not-working-using-iis7)

The error is when I try to run the project from vs2012 with asp net debugging enabled I get the following error:

```
Unable to start debugging on the web server. 
The web server is not configured correctly. 
See help for common configuration errors.
```

After so many tries I decide to create a new Asp Net Mvc 4/c# application and I could get asp net debug to work in visual studio 2012.

So I decided to copy file by file from one project to another to check where the problem started. I found out that when I enable ssl connection the debug stop working.

**For my application**

- I have set SSL and Client certificate required for my application
- Enabled http and https protocol

Also, In VS2012 Project properties I have changed the Project Url to

```
 https://localhost/Gedi
```

Which is the url for my project.

If I can find the solution here, then I update the other post which I believe will be very useful for future reference.

Is there any other special configuration I need to change in order to enable asp.net debugging when using https requests?

EDIT 1:

my web.config file

```
<compilation batch="true" debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" explicit="false"
maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="10000" maxBatchSize="10000" 
numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" strict="false" 
tempDirectory="C:\Windows\Temp" urlLinePragmas="false">
```

Comment: what do you have the Virtual Directory setup as in regards to Port do you have a virtual directory setup..?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest thing first the web.config file

You need to make sure your web.config file contains:

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />
```

Depending on what your default language is of course.

Comment: This is what I have: <compilation batch="true" debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" explicit="false" maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="10000" maxBatchSize="10000" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" strict="false" tempDirectory="C:\Windows\Temp" urlLinePragmas="false">

Comment: where is the Ending tag for Complilation /> ..?

Comment: Look at this site from Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site

Comment: Its is there.. just failed to copy the whole line. The thing is what is missing for a https. I start to believe that or it is not possible to debug when you use https or it is a very simple stuff..